# How to receive EnumMap from client in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Our system has multiple filter in user interface and passes the filter type & search text as map to Spring boot REST end point. We have modeled a Enum with all possible filter options as below,

```
public enum TypeEnum {
    TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3;
}
```

The below code works,

```
@GetMapping("/types/filter")
public void filterTypesByCriteria(@RequestParam Map<String, String> map) {
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

But when we tried with EnumMap for multiple filters, but it didn't work.

```
@GetMapping("/types/filter")
public void filterTypesByCriteria(@RequestParam EnumMap<AuditFilterEnum, String> map) {
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Kindly help us

Stack trace

```
argument type mismatch
    Controller [com.trailapps.controller.TypeController]
    Method [public void com.trailapps.controller.TypeController.filterTypesByCriteria(java.util.EnumMap<com.trailapps.controller.enums.TypeEnum, java.lang.String>)] with argument values: [0] [type=java.util.LinkedHashMap] [value={TYPE1=12, TYPE2=13}]
```

Comment: Please update the question with request payload along with `EnumMap`

Comment: Thank you @AlexpandiyanChokkan ,  Request payload http://localhost:9090/types/filter?TYPE1=12&TYPE2=13